# How to expanded collapse item horizontally inside navigation drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer

I want to add expanded collapse item horizontally inside navigation drawer. Is there any example or github code. Below i have added the image so that you can able to understand what i am trying to say.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this result using Expansion Tile:

```
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expansion Tile'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ExpansionTile(
              onExpansionChanged: (b) {
                setState(() {
                  _isExpanded = !_isExpanded; //using set state just to exemplify
                });
              },
              title: Text('Expand items'),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100),
                child: Icon(_isExpanded
                    ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                    : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 60),
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text('First child'),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 60),
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text('Second child'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom drawer.

[Check this example](https://dartpad.dev/a8764aff33b56e2435bb923075e6b11a)

You can do something similar to achieve the results as in your image.

Hope this helps!